# Automatically serve html page with data from server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I have a HTML page that I'd like to contain a list of other pages. These other pages are stored in a particular directory on my server. What's the best way to have the server send the page containing the list with the up-to-date list of pages? I'd like each item to be a link, if that's possible as well.

to summarize for clarity:

1. I have some webpages in a directory on my server, let's call it `/dir.`
2. I have a page that's a list of the webpages in `/dir` that I need to keep up to date. since files are added to `/dir` frequently, it wouldn't make sense to hard-code the links into the page every time I add a new page to `/dir.`
3. I'm looking for a way to keep the list on the page up to date with links to all the files in `/dir`, ideally from the server.

I'm using a Node.js server with Express.

Answer (score 0):

If your index html page is in the same directory as your list of pages, one way to create a hyperlink to the up-to-date list is to use this formula for each page:

```
<a href="./newPageName.html"> This text will be hyperlinked </a>
```

"./" will tell your code to look for the file starting from the same directory location as your index html.

---

If the html file you want to link is in a folder within the index's directory location:

```
<a href="./folderName/newPageName.html"> This text will be hyperlinked </a>
```

---

If the file is in the same directory, but a different folder, "../" will send you outside of the current directory's folder. From there, you can navigate to where the file is stored.

```
<a href="../folderName/newPageName.html"> This text will be hyperlinked </a>
```

---

Here is an example from my own code. I used an unorganized list, making each additional link a list item, as I found it, well, more 'organized'. All of these files are stored within their own folders ("lab2" "lab3" "lab4" "lab5") within a parent directory "art101". Because my main index html (the one containing all these linked index.html files) is directly in "art101" (not in a folder within "art101"), I don't have to use "../" to navigate out to "art101".

```
<ul id="labs">
  <li> <a href="lab2/index.html" target="_blank"> lab2 - html and css starter</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="lab3/index.html" target="_blank"> lab3 - file structure/transfer</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="lab4/index.html" target="_blank"> lab4 - problem solving </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="lab5/index.html" target="_blank"> lab5 - data types & variables</a> </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this makes sense/helps!

Comment: this is pretty useful, but what I'm mostly looking for is a server-side way to do this, as the pages in this directory have different names and new pages get added pretty frequently, so hard-coding the names in wouldn't really be feasible.

Comment: It'll be nice if you can also point out the node.js modules / code that could help generating these kind of HTML.